# Node.js error handling to check property value

Tags: javascript, node.js

Look how ugly it is. It has been a while I'm doing this, something still my app crash when I'm careless. How to get rid of double if here? I have to check if the result has something first else my app will crash because used property is undefined. I think this is a common pain in js.

```
module.exports.verify_email_and_token = function(req,res,next){
    Stripe_token.verify(req.body.email, req.body.token, function(err,result){
        if(result){
            if(result.used == 0){
                res.json(1); // 1 mean succeed
            }
        }else{
            res.json(0) // 0 mean failed
        }
    });
}
```

Above code has no error, just that I'm looking for more efficient way to write it.

Comment: Why don't you just return `res.json(result)` in case of success and `res.json(err)` in case of error? I'm assuming you return objects.

Comment: I use mongoose, like findOneAndUpdate will not return any err, the result is null is not err.

Comment: You can try setting up a middleware like a factory. There, you execute your checks. For instance, execute the query, if undefined then `return reject(error : 'error description')` else `return resolve(whatYouFound)`. Then you can catch them  as I told you in the previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a more condensed version using arrow functions (available in node 6.0+):

```
module.exports.verify_email_and_token = function(req,res,next) {
  Stripe_token.verify(req.body.email, req.body.token,
    res => res.json(result && result.used ? 1 : 0));
```

The semantics are slightly different, but I think that it fixes a bug in your code above.  Now if there is a `result`, and `used` property is falsy, then 0 is sent to `res.json()`.

In your code, in that situation, `res.json` is never called.

Comment: slick using && method within the function

Answer (score 0):

You can **assign** the result to an object, this way the object exist beforehand avoiding one **if**.

```
module.exports.verify_email_and_token = function(req,res,next){
    Stripe_token.verify(req.body.email, req.body.token, function(err,result){
            const _result = Object.assign({}, result);
            if(_result.used == 0){
                res.json(1); // 1 mean succeed
            }
            else{
                res.json(1);
            }

    });
}
```